# How to insert BLOB and CLOB files in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, qt4

I want to store images and .docx/.doc, .pptx/.ppt, .pdf files using the front end of my software. I don't understand how to implement this and how to insert the BLOB and CLOB files into the table. Please help.

I am using Kubuntu 11.04, MySQL5, Qt 4.7.3.

Answer (score 44):

Two ways:

1 - Use a [LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function -

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1, LOAD_FILE('data.png'));
```

2 - Insert file as hex string, e.g. -

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES 
  (1, x'89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D494844520000001000000010080200000090916836000000017352474200AECE1CE90000000467414D410000B18F0BFC6105000000097048597300000EC300000EC301C76FA8640000001E49444154384F6350DAE843126220493550F1A80662426C349406472801006AC91F1040F796BD0000000049454E44AE426082');
```

Comment: A 3rd option is close to the 2nd one and reads as `INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D494844520000001000000010080200000090916836000000017352474200AECE1CE90000000467414D410000B18F0BFC6105000000097048597300000EC300000EC301C76FA8640000001E49444154384F6350DAE843126220493550F1A80662426C349406472801006AC91F1040F796BD0000000049454E44AE426082);`.

Comment: The following is not working:

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1, LOAD_FILE(data.png));

Comment: Check if the file exists, check the path, check the file size, is it more or less them `max_allowed_packet`. Do you have FILE privilege? What type of BLOB field, is it enough to store the file?

Comment: The output shows that a value has been inserted into the table but while retrieving it shows NULL

Comment: I would also be very thankful if anyone can help me with the concept of downloading files from database. I mean for example if i upload some .pdf or .jpg files then how can a client download it?

Comment: insert into pic values(LOAD_FILE("home/pkr/Desktop/DSC09566.JPG"));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

Comment: Output-select * from pic;
+------+
| Pic  |
+------+
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: The LOAD_FILE function is working good. Maybe you have some warnings, try to see them - SHOW WARNINGS.

Comment: Doesn't the filename need to be in quotes?

Comment: Yes, it should be quoted.

Answer (score 16):

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(id, blob_col) VALUES(1, LOAD_FILE('/full/path/to/file/myfile.png')
```

LOAD_FILE has many conditions attached to it.  From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file):

> LOAD_FILE(file_name)
>
> Reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. To use this
>   function, the file must be located on the server host, you must
>   specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE
>   privilege. The file must be readable by all and its size less than
>   max_allowed_packet bytes. If the secure_file_priv system variable is
>   set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be
>   located in that directory.
>
> If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the
>   preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function returns NULL.

Also, there there are bugs with LOAD_FILE in Linux.   See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38403 for the bug, and [MySQL LOAD_FILE returning NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607486/mysql-load-file-returning-null) for workarounds.  On Ubuntu 12.04, MySQL 5.5.32, this works for me:

1. Copy file to /tmp
2. Change ownership to mysql user `chown mysql:mysql /tmp/yourfile`
3. Log into mysql as mysql root user so you are sure you have FILE privilege
4. Run your insert statement

Comment: The `secure_file_priv` hint saved my day. Use

`mysql> SELECT @@secure_file_priv;` to see the actual value

Answer (score 11):

Or you could merely use the MySQL Workbench, select the rows, last rows, insert a row without the blob, then just right click and select "Load Value From File".

[image]

Comment: THIS! Exactly what I needed but didnt know exist. Blame me.

Comment: Bad solution, completely relying on third party tool

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1, LOAD_FILE(data.png));
```

won't work but

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1, LOAD_FILE('data.png'));
```

should (assuming data.png exists in the local directory)

Answer (score 2):

for those People who are getting "Column 'image' cannot be null" error while saving Blob through query :-

Open your MySql Command Line Client and login with root user and type

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

this will show you the secure path used by MySql to access the files. something like

```
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                 |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| secure_file_priv | /var/lib/mysql-files/ |
+------------------+-----------------------+
```

you can either paste files inside this folder or change the "secure_file_priv" variable value to "empty string" so that it can read file from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql workbench, just right click on the field (cell) and select 'load value from file' option and then browse to the file and click open and then click on apply. It will automatically generate query like this

```
UPDATE `dbname`.`tablename` SET `columnname` = ? WHERE (`row` = '1');
```