# how to remove query error?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `FC_Categories`
(
   `CategoryID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `CategoryName` VARCHAR (15),
   `Description` TEXT,
   `Picture` LONGBLOB,
    UNIQUE (`CategoryName`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryID`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
# Dumping data for table FC_Categories 
# INSERT INTO FC_Categories VALUES (1, 'Beverages', 'Soft drinks, coffees,teas, beers, and ales')
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO `FC_Categories` VALUES (1, 'Beverages', 'Soft
>   drinks, coffees, teas,' at line 14

Comment: how to remove error of this query?

Comment: @Arif I can't even read the query let along fix it!

Comment: The end of your query is truncated with [...] is that intentional?

Comment: [**See Working Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55b7e) you have missed terminator

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729824/how-to-insert-blob-and-clob-files-in-mysql

Comment: At least I do not see ';' after CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: You have missed ' ' for the Picture value while inserting.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/926cc/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter field name

```
INSERT INTO FC_Categories ('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5','field6','field7','field8') VALUES (1, 'Beverages', 'Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales', 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
```