# import mysql blob data using php

Tags: mysql, blob

i am trying to save image data in mysql using blob format
these are inserted and retrieved correctly using php
i have a problem , i need to create a separate sql file for certain data which includes blob data when i try to import the sql file it is not able to import the blob data

```
include 'database.inc.php';
if (isset($_FILES['sqlfile']) && !empty($_FILES['sqlfile'])) {
$filename=$_FILES['sqlfile']['name'];
$tmp_filename=$_FILES['sqlfile']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_filename, $filename);
$file_content=file_get_contents($filename);
$commands = explode(';',trim($file_content));
foreach ($commands as $command) {
    if(mysql_query($command)){
        //header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    } else {
        //echo 'Failed to import with following command <br/>'.$command;
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to properly encode the data in the SQL file, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10732588/1015327) answer to ["How to insert BLOB and CLOB files in MySQL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729824/how-to-insert-blob-and-clob-files-in-mysql).