# Updating the image stored in a LONGBLOB column in mysql

Tags: mysql, blob

I tried using LOAD_FILE function that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729824/how-to-insert-blob-and-clob-files-in-mysql) so this is my query:

```
UPDATE 
`table1` 
SET 
`field1` = LOAD_FILE('C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\img.jpg')
WHERE 
`id` = '1';
```

and I get this error:

> Error Code: 1048. Column 'profile_pic' cannot be null

I'm sure that the path is correct, so why do I get that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use forward slashes (`/`), not backslashes (`\`), even on Windows.  What you have is an escaped `U`, which is just a `U`, etc:  `'C:UsersAdminPicturesimg.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

To add the longblob value, you need to add the file in bytes.

mysql code:

1) Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `temp`.`example` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `page` LONGBLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL , 

PRIMARY KEY (`id`))  ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

2) Insert into:

```
INSERT INTO `example` (`id`, `page`) VALUES (NULL, NULL);
```

3) Update id=1:

```
UPDATE example  SET page=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

WHERE id=1
```

[BLOB] mouse click save name.jpg