# Bulk upload photos to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlite, blob, photo, migrate

Good Evening,

I have a project to move a database from Sqlite to Mysql. Datagrip was used to move most of the data straight across, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to like the Blob data which is PNG image files.

I've managed to find a tool which has exported the images back to PNG and named them according to the ID of the row.

Would anyone have any idea how I can now reverse this and insert them back into the Mysql database against the correct ID into the Photo column?

Sorry if this seems a basic question, I was hoping migrating the database would be a few clicks.

Thanks for any advice.

Kind Regards

Comment: Sounds like you might need to write a custom script to do this in bulk, based on the directory that the PNG files are stored in. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729824/how-to-insert-blob-and-clob-files-in-mysql)

Comment: Hi Jamie, I'm thinking the same. I'm not sure if Python could do this? All I need is a script that loops over every image and adds it to a single table into the photo column based of the files name. So file 1 would go against ID 1 etc. Once I find a solution I will post here unless someone has any idea. Thank you for your response though.