# sql unable to insert

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

im trying to insert some data into a table, mysql gives syntax error and i cant find, may i get help please

```
INSERT INTO museums(id,name,rate,phone,opening_hours,closing_hours,location,image)
VALUES(1,"The Royal Automobile Museum",4.7,065411392,10:00:00, 7:00:00,"At Tibbiyya, Amman",LOAD_FILE('C:\xampp\htdocs\wael\images\The Royal Automobile Museum.jpg'));
```

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':00:00, 7:00:00,"At Tibbiyya, Amman",LOAD_FILE('C:\xampp\htdocs\wael\images\T...' at line 2
```

Comment: Can you post a database scheme? I suspect your `opening/closing hours` are strings? There you have an error.. Maybe put `"10:00:00"`

Comment: data types or size of column doesnt fit the sample data probably. please have a look museum table and compare with data which you want to insert

Comment: yep, the time need to be inside double quotes, but still doesn't insert image, it gives me error " image can't be null"

Comment: These might be helpful. [How to use LOAD_FILE to load a file into a MySQL blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229951/how-to-use-load-file-to-load-a-file-into-a-mysql-blob) and [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: @aasemshoshari . For *"Column 'image' cannot be null" error* possible solution... [How to insert BLOB and CLOB files in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57113148/7376590)

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
INSERT INTO museums (id,name,rate,phone,opening_hours,closing_hours,location,image) VALUES (1,'The Royal Automobile Museum',4.7,065411392,'10:00:00','7:00:00','At Tibbiyya, Amman','LOAD_FILE(''C:\xampp\htdocs\wael\images\The Royal Automobile Museum.jpg'')');
```

It gives error probably due to ' mark before C:/// and after jpg. so you need to change it to '' instead of '

Answer (score 0):

use ' for hours and phone

```
insert into museums
    (
       id
     , name
     , rate
     , phone
     , opening_hours
     , closing_hours
     , location
     , image
    )
    values
    (1
    , 'The Royal Automobile Museum'
    , 4.7
    , '065411392'
    , '10:00:00'
    , '7:00:00'
    , 'At Tibbiyya, Amman'
    , LOAD_FILE('C:\xampp\htdocs\wael\images\The Royal Automobile Museum.jpg'))
```