# MariaDB Insert BLOB Image

Tags: mysql, image, null, blob, mariadb

**What I want to do?**

- I want to insert a picture into a MariaDB database using the command line, using the LOAD_FILE fuction.

**What's wrong?**

- I always get a NULL return.
- I **don't** want a solution like: This is bad style and I haven't seen this so far - try to store the full path! I **want** to store this picture in this database and **not** the path.

**System**

- *mysql*  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.17-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
- *ArchLinux* 4.7.2-1-ARCH
- A picture called *Test.jpg* (817KB) under `/home/user/Blob/Test.jpg`, `/tmp/Test.jpg` and even under `/var/lib(mysql/images/Test.jpg`
- The picture belongs to the user and group mysql and has every permission I could imagine

  ```
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 mysql mysql 836508 20. Feb 2016  Test.jpg
  ```
- I tested several users i.e. *mysql* and *root*

**Database**

I have created a database called *Blobtest* with a table called *Test* with a Blob and a Longblob variable.

```
CREATE TABLE Test (id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,longblobimg LONGBLOB NOT NULL, blobimg BLOB NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));

+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| longblobimg | longblob         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| blobimg     | blob             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Insert Statement**

(in this case with the /home/user/directory)

```
INSERT INTO Test VALUES (1, LOAD_FILE('/home/user/Blob/Test.jpg'), LOAD_FILE('/home/user/Blob/Test.jpg'));
```

**Approach to solving this problem**

I followed the instructions at this link [MySQL LOAD_FILE() loads null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069054/mysql-load-file-loads-null-values)

- I  have execute permission on the parent directory
- The FILE privilege is explicily granted. (GRANT FILE on . TO mysql@localhost)
- I have flushed privileges
- I have logged out and logged back in
- I have tested several directories, belonging to *mysql* or *user* via `chmod` and `chown` command
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';` is set to 16 MB or 16777216, picture is 817KB *big*
- `select HEX(LOAD_FILE('/home/user/Blob/Test.jpg'));` returns NULL

**Solutions?**

I don't know if this is a bug in MariaDB or if I'm the only one who has this problem. 
To point this out again: I **want** to store the picture within this database. I **don't** want to store the path. This is an experiment, I have to store the picture in the database.

It would be awesome if somebody can help me with this problem!

Comment: Question: is your "my.cnf" configuration file got this parameter: local-infile=1 ?

Comment: I had no parameter like this - I added: local-infile=1 to "my.cnf" but still got this error.

Comment: you need to place this parameter after the tag [mysql] and the tag [mysqld] to explicit the mysql client and server are allowed to use local files (but I use this parameter in general to use "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE". Your issue is maybe related to your Linux distribution.  I'm using latest Linux Mint and "SELECT LOAD_FILE(...)" runs well

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: Check that selinux is not preventing access.

Comment: @FragBis Thank you for your effort so far. I set the parameter behind tag [mysql]  and [mysqld] - unfortunately the same NULL return.

Comment: @RickJames I don't use selinux or apparmor - I have seen this at some other help sites, but good thought. I'm using mariadb-clients-10.1.17-1 from the arch linux repository.

Comment: Then, you could have a look on this thread: https://forum.piwik.org/t/load-data-infile/8765/33 It is more focused on "LOAD DATA INFILE" issue but this seems to be the same "file access" issue for mysql user. Quote: "I finally fixed it. I just add mysql user to psaserv group and after mysql restart worked. 
I know that this might be a security risk but i can't find any other way to make it work". Hope it will help you a little more.

Answer (score 2):

[`LOAD_FILE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/load_file/) only works if the file is located on the database server. If the server is on the same system as the file, then there should be no problems loading it. If so, I'd recommend opening a bug report about inadequate error reporting.

#### Other ways to binary load data into the server

Usually connectors provide methods for loading binary data into the database. For example the MariaDB C connector provides [`mysql_stmt_send_long_data`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_stmt_send_long_data/).

Another option is to convert the data into a non-binary encoding (e.g. base64 or hex) on the client side and decode it on the server (base64 with [`FROM_BASE64`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/from_base64/) and hex with [`UNHEX`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/unhex/)).