# How to insert image into mysql db table?

Tags: mysql

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtFKo.png)    mysql> insert into test (id,img)
           values(1,LOAD_FILE('/home/ubundu/pic.jpg'));
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.55 sec)

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------+------+
| id   | img  |
+------+------+
|    1 | NULL |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069054/mysql-load-file-loads-null-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL LOAD\_FILE() loads null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069054/mysql-load-file-loads-null-values)

Comment: Please go through these links, and if nothing works, come back to this question and update with what you have tried.