# syntax error while loading image in mysql DB

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql  Ver 14.14.I have created a mysql table with the attributes id, image_name and myimage.

[table "unstruct_tab1" description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJcy1.png)

"myimage" is a column to hold image location.
Am trying to insert image location using the following syntax.

```
mysql> insert into unstruct_tab1 (id,image,myimage) select 11, 'kola3.jpg' , BulkColumn from Openrowset(Bulk 'Linux path of image location...', Single_BLOB) as img;
```

Am ending up with the following error for the above syntax:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(Bulk 'Linux location...', BLOB) as img' at line 1

Kindly help me out to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that syntax is for SQL server.

In MySQL, use [`LOAD_FILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file):

```
insert into unstruct_tab1 (id, image, myimage) 
values(11, 'kola3.jpg', load_file('Linux path of image location'));
```

Comment: When i try the above syntax.

mysql> insert into unstruct_tab1 (id, image_name, myimage) values(100, 'kola_100.jpg', load_file('Linux path..'));

"myimage" column is stored as ' null '

Comment: @swathi - You probably don't have privileges. [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069054/mysql-load-file-loads-null-values)

Comment: Is there any other way to load image in the mysql table ?

Comment: privileges regarding Mysql version or it could be cluster ?

Comment: @swathi - Please check the question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069054/mysql-load-file-loads-null-values